# Angular 2 Kendo UI Telerik grid paging reloads the page

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a Kendo-ui (Angular 2) grid (paging enabled) ,when i click on a page button, it reloads the page (the href attribute value i s '#' in the button links). how to fix this issue ?

grid:

```
                        <kendo-grid [data]="items" [pageSize]="state.take" [filter]="state.filter" [skip]="state.skip" [sort]="state.sort" [sortable]="true" [pageable]="{ buttonCount: 8, info: true}" [scrollable]="'none'" (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)" (filterChange)="onFilterChanged($event)"
                        (pageChange)="onGridPageChange($event)">
```

pageChangeEvent:

```
onGridPageChange(e: PageChangeEvent) {
    this.state.skip = e.skip;
    this.state.take = e.take;
    this.loadInvoiceItems();
}
```

[image]

Comment: if i remember right from when i used it, you cant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did encounter this problem before. Please use DataStateChangeEvent instead.

```
public dataStateChange(state: DataStateChangeEvent): void {
    Object.assign(this.state, state);
    this.loadInvoiceItems();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working on the [official demo page](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-binding/data-binding/).

Comment: yes, i know . but the problem is it does not work in my setup